# Update the internal database of an Android app using a real-time database

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android app, I want to update my Internal database using a real-time database like Firebase. My target is, even if in offline mode, users of the app can be viewed the content by using the internal database. And every time they connect to the internet, the Internal database should be updated. how can I do this

Comment: Please give more details and descriptions about what you are going to do.

Comment: Internal database should be updated via cloud database because I want to see the content even if in offline mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the firebase offline too no need for internal database by using 
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`
 check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)